# Cannot create a table having a column whose name contains commas in Hive metastore

Tags: pyspark, databricks, azure-databricks, hive-metastore

Tried to create a delta table from spark data frame using below command:

```py
destination_path = "/dbfs/mnt/kidneycaredevstore/delta/df_corr_feats_spark_4"

df_corr_feats_spark.write.format("delta").option("delta.columnMapping.mode", "name").option("path",destination_path).saveAsTable("CKD_Features_4")
```

Getting below error:

> AnalysisException: Cannot create a table having a column whose name contains commas in Hive metastore. Table: `default`.`abc_features_4`; Column: Adverse, abc initial encounter

Please note that there are around 6k columns in this data frame and it is developed by data scientist generate feature. So, we cannot rename columns.

How to fix this error? Can any configuration change in Metastore solve this issue?

Answer (score 2):

[Column mapping](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/delta/delta-column-mapping) feature requires writer version 5 and reader version 2 of [Delta protocol](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/delta/versioning), therefore you need to specify this when saving:

```
df_corr_feats_spark.write.format("delta")
    .option("delta.columnMapping.mode", "name")
    .option("delta.minReaderVersion", "2")
    .option("delta.minWriterVersion", "5")
    .option("path", destination_path)
    .saveAsTable("CKD_Features_4")
```

Comment: This does not work even after setting minReader and writer version. Here is my query - create table testDB.testTable (`ID` string, `NAME` string, `A,B` string)  using delta TBLPROPERTIES('delta.minReaderVersion' = '2','delta.minWriterVersion' = '5','delta.columnMapping.mode' = 'name')